# Who were the Catholic popes before Francis I who used names not of Latin, Greek or Jewish origin?

Tags: religion, catholic-church, pope

Who were the Catholic popes before the current *Francis I* who used names not of Latin, Greek or Jewish origin? Particularly, names of Germanic origin, like Francis.

Comment: just curious, which popes have Jewish names?

Comment: @LouisRhys: John, for example.

Comment: Yarbut yarbut ... just because a name *was* Latin, Greek or Jewish doesn't mean it originated in those cultures. Every culture evolves, absorbing other influences, and eventually becoming something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T.E.D.'s answer (despite its to date 7 up-votes) is wrong on two counts. First, Hormisdas is definitely Persian (Hormizd is a Middle Persian form of the divine name Ahura Mazda), as has been mentioned by choster. Second, “etymonline” says only that the English name Francis is borrowed in the first instance from French. Ultimately it is of Germanic origin.

Answer (score 10):

[Hormisdas](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07470a.htm) is of Persian origin, and he possibly took the name to honor a Persian noble named Hormizd.

In the tenth century we had a Pope Landus, or Lando, and various sources say that this name is of Anglo-Saxon origin. Lando was also his given name, however, and I find it unlikely than an Italian from Sabina would have been given an Anglo-Saxon name. What can be said is that he was the [last pope to have taken an original name](http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/lookout/every-pope-one-chart-see-francis-bucked-tradition-155211410.html), until Francis.

Incidentally, *francis* seems to have been the Latin name for the Celts or the Suebi, and not Germanic as you suggest.

Comment: Damn, George Lucas had his long grubby licensing arms even there!!!

Comment: Bet *his* Popemobile was the fastest hunkajunk in the Sistine Chapel!

Comment: @mh01 She'll make the Castel run in less than 12 *piedi*. And yes, I know the *pied* is a unit of distance.

Comment: @choster - I would have expected nothing else. :)

Answer (score 7):

Wikipedia has a complete list of [Papal names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_name). Counting this week's Francis, 81 different names have been used. There are some names that arguably may be Italian rather than Latin (eg:[Lando](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Lando)), but none with undisputed roots outside of those three languages.

Note that etymology Online actually lists Francis as [French in origin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Francis&allowed_in_frame=0), which would make it of Romantic (ultimiately Roman) origin, not Germanic.

> masc. proper name, from French François, from Old French Franceis, from Late Latin Franciscus, literally "Frankish;" cognate with French and frank.

Thus Francis might not count either.

Comment: While we are vaguely on the subject, I have to make note of my all-time favorite Pope name: [Pope Hilarious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Hilarius) If [Father Guido Sarducci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father_Guido_Sarducci) is ever elected Pope, he should take Pope Hilarious II.

Comment: +1, I was in the middle of writing similar answer with a mention of Lando. I believe all the rest are Latin, Greek or Hebrew, with Lando falling into Latin category, as he was also known as Landus.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski - There were actually a few others I could mention. Almost all are Italians who kept their birth names. The further you go back the more debatable the difference between Latin and Italian is though.

Comment: The *Franks* from which the cognate names *Frank* and *Francis* derive were a Germanic tribe that invaded and conquered Gaul during the death throes of the Western Empire. This clearly makes the name *Germanic* in ultimate source. It is a common male name throughout much of Central Europe.

Comment: From the OED [1928]: `It is usually believed that the Franks were named for their national weapon, OE *franca*, javelin; [as the Saxons were named for theirs, the *seax* or knife]. The notion that the name derived from the adj. meaning 'free' ... was already current in the 10th century; but the real relation between the words seems to be the reverse of this.`

Comment: The French are the descendants of Germanic tribes which eventually became latinized, so being of French origin does not necessarily imply also being of Roman origin, ultimately for the same reason for which being of, say, Romanian origin does not immediately imply the same either, since plenty of Romanian words are of Slavic or unknown origin; see [substratum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratum_(linguistics)).